# Call .NET Web API method whenever a new file is added to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-eventhub, azure-blob-storage

I have a method called **ReadFileData(string blobStorageFilePath)** in my .NET Web API project. This method reads the text content from Azure Blob file. The azure blob storage file path is passed via the parameter in this method. Till now a client application (web) was calling this method to read file data but now I have to automate this process.

So, is it possible to call this web API method (by some way) whenever a new file is added to azure blob storage automatically? So this way there will be no need of any client application.

Which approach should I use to implement this process?

Any working example will be appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew this should be the answer, not just a comment

Comment: How you are uploading the file to azure blob. If you are doing through the code, then you can make the web api call in that method itself. If you are also uploading through portal, then use azure functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a webjob to your Azure app service and install the Azure Webjobs SDK. Then you can easily trigger your read with a simple declarative blob trigger

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to

```
public static void CopyBlob([BlobTrigger("input/{name}")] TextReader input,
    [Blob("output/{name}")] out string output)
{
    output = input.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function

You can create a function triggered by Azure Blob storage. Please see the link for the complete example