# Testing Azure Blob Storage SDK

Tags: testing, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk

I found this great [Getting Started Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=environment-variable-windows) for the Azure Blob Storage SDK and how to connect to my storage account.

A quick prototype showed that it already works, but I want to ensure this and the logic behind it via tests (either unit or integration tests).

I found this resource on an [Azure Testing Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/core-test-readme?view=azure-java-stable) that can record HTTP requests of a pipeline and was wondering whether this is applicable to the Blob Storage SDK as well?

Are there any other options to properly test my applications code interaction with the Blob Storage SDK?

My idea would for example be:

1. Call a method on my client with a parameter
2. Take the blob name from the passed parameter and make a call to the blob storage container
3. Validate that the call was made to the correct container and blob via a test case

Comment: 1. your links are c# so why tagged java? 2. the sdk should have been tested by microsoft so what's the point of test again?

Comment: I will remove the Java tag, thanks for pointing out! The getting started it easily portable to Java.
I want to test my application, not the SDK. But I want to make sure that is properly integrates and my logic supplies the SDK with the information required. Either I mock it out or I find something suitable to test it together, I guess,. That was my intent

Comment: check this https://itbackyard.com/tag/storage/ and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794583/how-to-make-integration-test-for-azure-blob-storage-with-c-sharp/70794584#70794584

Comment: @gerstams did it help, you indeed welcome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make integration test for Azure Blob Storage with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794583/how-to-make-integration-test-for-azure-blob-storage-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Hey @gerstams, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

•   I too just tried to follow the documentation link for various tasks to be performed regarding the Azure Blob storage using the .Net v12 SDK and the results were successful as follows: -

[image: Azure Blob storage quickstart]
[image: Azure Blob storage v12 .net]

Also, if you want to call a method/task on your client/application using a parameter with respect to Blob storage, you can surely do so by using the **‘BlobServiceClient’** class. To know more on how to use it, please refer to the documentation link below: -

https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-korean/dotnet_introduction.html

It clearly states on how to call the service name client and the methods for which to use the parameters for performing various tasks as shown in the sample code from that document below: -

```
  namespace Azure.<group>.<service_name> {

// main service client class
public class <service_name>Client {

    // simple constructors; don't use default parameters
    public <service_name>Client(<simple_binding_parameters>);
    public <service_name>Client(<simple_binding_parameters>, <service_name>ClientOptions options);

    // 0 or more advanced constructors
    public <service_name>Client(<advanced_binding_parameters>, <service_name>ClientOptions options = default);

    // mocking constructor
    protected <service_name>Client();

    // service methods (synchronous and asynchronous)
    public virtual Task<Response<<model>> <service_operation>Async(<parameters>, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    public virtual Response<model> <service_operation>(<parameters>, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

    // other members
}

// options for configuring the client
public class <service_name>ClientOptions : ClientOptions {

   }
  }
```

Also, I would suggest you to please refer this community thread: -

[Call .NET Web API method whenever a new file is added to Azure Blob Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46069066/call-net-web-api-method-whenever-a-new-file-is-added-to-azure-blob-storage)